# pac cli paportal download

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-portals

Everytime I download a "power portal" with the pac cli command:

```
pac paportal download -id <guid> --path ./ --overwrite true
```

Many of the files seem to be regenerated with new short guids on the end, although they haven't changed. And the sitestettings.yml file gets re-ordered so it shows a bunch of changes.

Below I made one change to a site setting, and I have 134 changes.

Can this be avoided? It makes it frustrating to track actual changes in source control.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple records with the same name, then the short guid will be appended as file/folders cannot have same names, if you avoid creating records with exact same names (active/inactive both) you should not face this issue